# Nav menù doesn't display selected pages

Tags: php, menus, navigation

I've included Elementor inside my custom plugin and now I'm creating my wp site layout.
I've noticed that my nav menu will show all the pages I have created for my website, but from the settings I've only included three pages to show. This is the code I have in my `header.php` file

```php
wp_head(); 

wp_nav_menu( 
    [
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        'menu_id' => 'header-menu',
        'container' => 'nav',
    ] 
);
```

Is there something I've missed in the code or I need to change some setting from the menù page in wp dashboard?

Comment: did you assign your nav menu to the `header-menu` nav menu location in the settings? It's not enough to create a menu, you have to assign it

Comment: Since I'm creating a custom theme using elementor I'm not sure about this, where I need to check this setting?

Comment: it's a standard WordPress feature, the menus are in the menu named menu in the side menu, if you're building your menus using Elementor then you would need to ask in an Elementor community as Elementor is offtopic here. Any standard WordPress user guide including the official documentation on wordpress.org should be able to explain how nav menus are assigned